# View [auth.passwords.reset] not found

Tags: php, laravel

I have `route`

```
Route::get('passwords/reset/{token?}','Auth\ResetPasswordController@showResetForm');
```

`ResetPasswordController`

```
//Show form to seller where they can reset password
public function showResetForm(Request $request, $token = null)
{
    return view('auth.passwords.reset')->with(
        ['token' => $token, 'email' => $request->email]
    ); 
}
```

And `reset.blade.php` inside `auth\passwords\`

```
 <form action="passwords/email"method = 'post'>

   <h4 style = 'text-align:center'>Reset Your Password</h4>
   <div class="form-group">

      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="exampleInputPassword1" placeholder="Enter Your Email Here" style = 'text-align:center'>
  </div>

   <div>
     <button type="submit" value="submit">Send Email To Reset Password  
  </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

When I try to visit `domain-name/password/reset` it gives

> View [auth.passwords.reset] not found.

Although I have `reset.blade.php` like `views/auth/passwords/reset.blade.php`

It's not loading the `view` that is already there, and the path is specified by `laravel` itself that `auth.passwords.reset` can't be found.

Comment: that is something else @Script47

Comment: What is your folders names please add that .. are they start with capital letter??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if your folder names start with capital letters as it is case sensitive

```
public function showResetForm(Request $request, $token = null)
{

   // Here I have assumed your folders start with capital letters please put as per your structure
    return view('Auth.Passwords.reset')->with(
    ['token' => $token, 'email' => $request->email]
     ); 
 }
```

Comment: I tried that earlier, that was not working but now its working fine, thank you ! @Leena Patel